# Do chickpeas and kidney beans absorb salt when boiled in water with salt?

Tags: salt, indian-cuisine, boiling

As I've read [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/92662/75413), rice absorbs some salt when cooked/boiled. I'm interested about similar thing but about chickpeas and kidney beans.

So when I boil them in water, and add some salt, **would the salt stay just over the surface of chickpeas/beans or it will actually enter inside each piece?**

Why I'm interested in it because I tend to wash boiled (i.e., cooked) chickpeas and kidney beans with fresh water before using them to be part of another dish like cooking a little more with spices and oil. So I'm  not sure when I wash them, the salt is also washed or it does stay with them.

Answer (score 2):

Your actual question seems to be the opposite of your title.

Yes, salting the water will salt the beans to some extent.
Rinsing will not remove that salt from the interior, only that on the surface.

Comment: ... that is, after all, the whole reason for salting them in the first place.

Comment: @FuzzyChef there my be other reasons: https://www.seriouseats.com/salt-beans-cooking-soaking-water-good-or-bad

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late reply. Chickpeas are also considered beans right? I guess when you used word "beans" you meant for maybe all well known beans, including the two I mentioned.